# Problems when creating a windows service based on EI 6.1.1 wso2

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, wso2, windows-services

I am relative new in WSO2, and need some help with a issue.
The problem now is, in the server of my enterprise, my colleagues create the services by the ei6.1.1, and they run that batchs, to make the service running the correct link:

"C:\omniPOS\bin\integrator.bat"

"C:\omniPOS\wso2\msf4j\bin\carbon.bat"

"C:\omniPOS\wso2\broker\bin\wso2server.bat"

What i need is run this links in my service, to i be able to just run all of it with the service. Here follow the .conf that i am using to create the service by the EI6.1.1.

```
#********************************************************************
# working directory
#********************************************************************
wrapper.working.dir=${carbon_home}\\
# Java Main class.
# YAJSW: default is "org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain"
# DO NOT SET THIS PROPERTY UNLESS YOU HAVE YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION
# wrapper.java.mainclass=
#********************************************************************
# tmp folder
# yajsw creates temporary files named in_.. out_.. err_.. jna..
# per default these are placed in jna.tmpdir.
# jna.tmpdir is set in setenv batch file to <yajsw>/tmp
#********************************************************************
wrapper.tmp.path = ${jna_tmpdir}
#********************************************************************
# Application main class or native executable
# One of the following properties MUST be defined
#********************************************************************
# Java Application main class
wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=${wrapper_home}\/log\/wrapper.log
# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
#wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
#wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling by size.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kB) or
#  'm' (mB) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
# If wrapper.logfile does not contain the string ROLLNUM it will be automatically added as suffix of the file name
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m
# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title="WSO2 Carbon"
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Service and Posix Daemon Properties
#********************************************************************
# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name="WSO2CARBON"
# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname="WSO2 Carbon"
# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description="Carbon Kernel"
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper System Tray Properties
#********************************************************************
# enable system tray
wrapper.tray = false
# TCP/IP port. If none is defined multicast discovery is used to find the port
# Set the port in case multicast is not possible.
wrapper.tray.port = 15002
#********************************************************************
# Exit Code Properties
# Restart on non zero exit code
#********************************************************************
wrapper.on_exit.0=SHUTDOWN
wrapper.on_exit.default=RESTART
#********************************************************************
# Trigger actions on console output
#********************************************************************
# On Exception show message in system tray
wrapper.filter.trigger.0=Exception
wrapper.filter.script.0=scripts\/trayMessage.gv
wrapper.filter.script.0.args=Exception
#********************************************************************
# genConfig: further Properties generated by genConfig
#********************************************************************
placeHolderSoGenPropsComeHere=
wrapper.java.command = ${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\*.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.1 = org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
wrapper.app.parameter.2 = RUN
wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xbootclasspath\/a:${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\xboot\\*.jar
wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m
wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m
wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${carbon_home}\\repository\\logs\\heap-dump.hprof
wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8 = -Djava.endorsed.dirs=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\endorsed;${java_home}\\jre\\lib\\endorsed
wrapper.java.additional.9 = -Dcarbon.registry.root=\/
wrapper.java.additional.10 = -Dcarbon.home=${carbon_home}
wrapper.java.additional.11 = -Dwso2.server.standalone=true
wrapper.java.additional.12 = -Djava.command=${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.additional.13 = -Djava.io.tmpdir=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\tmp
wrapper.java.additional.14 = -Dcatalina.base=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\tomcat
wrapper.java.additional.15 = -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\tomcat\\tomcat-log.properties
wrapper.java.additional.16 = -Dcarbon.config.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\conf
wrapper.java.additional.17 = -Dcarbon.logs.path=${carbon_home}\\repository\\logs
wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dcomponents.repo=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\components\\plugins
wrapper.java.additional.19 = -Dconf.location=${carbon_home}\\conf
wrapper.java.additional.20 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\transactions.properties
wrapper.java.additional.21 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path=true
wrapper.java.additional.22 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
wrapper.java.additional.23 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple
wrapper.java.additional.24 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000
wrapper.java.additional.25 = -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dcarbon.extensions.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\extensions
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dcarbon.dropins.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\dropins
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dcarbon.external.lib.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\lib
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dcarbon.patches.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\patches
wrapper.java.additional.30 = -Dcarbon.servicepacks.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\servicepacks
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dcarbon.internal.lib.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib
wrapper.java.additional.32 = -Dskip.logging=true
wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dei.extendedURIBasedDispatcher=org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.IntegratorStatefulHandler
wrapper.java.additional.34 = -Dskip.logging.pattern=\/carbon*
wrapper.java.additional.35 = -Dtomcat.random.port.enable=true
wrapper.java.additional.36 = -Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true
wrapper.java.additional.37 = -Dcarbon.components.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\components
```

This configure is creating the windows service with port offset '0'. Now i need to use that to run all of those batchs's and create ports 9443 and 9447.
If anyone could help me, i would stay quite grateful. Thank you everyone.

Observation: After some tests in the server i found a bug: 'ERROR - JmsStore Store []. Could not create a new connection to the broker'. Please a need help, because i can't solve it alone. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be due to the 'Dtomcat.random.port.enable=true' in your wrapper.conf file. I did not observe any issue with the default wrapper.conf bundled with EI 6.1.1 pack.

Please use the following wrapper.conf file.

```
#********************************************************************
# working directory
#********************************************************************
wrapper.working.dir=${carbon_home}\\
# Java Main class.
# YAJSW: default is "org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain"
# DO NOT SET THIS PROPERTY UNLESS YOU HAVE YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION
# wrapper.java.mainclass=
#********************************************************************
# tmp folder
# yajsw creates temporary files named in_.. out_.. err_.. jna..
# per default these are placed in jna.tmpdir.
# jna.tmpdir is set in setenv batch file to <yajsw>/tmp
#********************************************************************
wrapper.tmp.path = ${jna_tmpdir}
#********************************************************************
# Application main class or native executable
# One of the following properties MUST be defined
#********************************************************************
# Java Application main class
wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=${wrapper_home}\/log\/wrapper.log
# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
#wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
#wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling by size.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kB) or
#  'm' (mB) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
# If wrapper.logfile does not contain the string ROLLNUM it will be automatically added as suffix of the file name
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m
# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title="WSO2 Carbon"
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Service and Posix Daemon Properties
#********************************************************************
# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name="WSO2CARBON"
# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname="WSO2 Carbon"
# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description="Carbon Kernel"
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper System Tray Properties
#********************************************************************
# enable system tray
wrapper.tray = true
# TCP/IP port. If none is defined multicast discovery is used to find the port
# Set the port in case multicast is not possible.
wrapper.tray.port = 15002
#********************************************************************
# Exit Code Properties
# Restart on non zero exit code
#********************************************************************
wrapper.on_exit.0=SHUTDOWN
wrapper.on_exit.default=RESTART
#********************************************************************
# Trigger actions on console output
#********************************************************************
# On Exception show message in system tray
wrapper.filter.trigger.0=Exception
wrapper.filter.script.0=scripts\/trayMessage.gv
wrapper.filter.script.0.args=Exception
#********************************************************************
# genConfig: further Properties generated by genConfig
#********************************************************************
placeHolderSoGenPropsComeHere=
wrapper.java.command = ${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\*.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.1 = org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
wrapper.app.parameter.2 = RUN
wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xbootclasspath\/a:${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\xboot\\*.jar
wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m
wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m
wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${carbon_home}\\repository\\logs\\heap-dump.hprof
wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8 = -Djava.endorsed.dirs=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\endorsed;${java_home}\\jre\\lib\\endorsed
wrapper.java.additional.9 = -Dcarbon.registry.root=\/
wrapper.java.additional.10 = -Dcarbon.home=${carbon_home}
wrapper.java.additional.11 = -Dwso2.server.standalone=true
wrapper.java.additional.12 = -Djava.command=${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.additional.13 = -Djava.io.tmpdir=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\tmp
wrapper.java.additional.14 = -Dcatalina.base=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\tomcat
wrapper.java.additional.15 = -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${carbon_home}\\conf\\tomcat\\tomcat-log.properties
wrapper.java.additional.16 = -Dcarbon.config.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\conf
wrapper.java.additional.17 = -Dcarbon.logs.path=${carbon_home}\\repository\\logs
wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dcomponents.repo=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\components\\plugins
wrapper.java.additional.19 = -Dconf.location=${carbon_home}\\conf
wrapper.java.additional.20 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib\\transactions.properties
wrapper.java.additional.21 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path=true
wrapper.java.additional.22 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
wrapper.java.additional.23 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple
wrapper.java.additional.24 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000
wrapper.java.additional.25 = -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dcarbon.extensions.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\extensions
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dcarbon.dropins.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\dropins
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dcarbon.external.lib.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\lib
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dcarbon.patches.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\patches
wrapper.java.additional.30 = -Dcarbon.servicepacks.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\servicepacks
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dcarbon.internal.lib.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\lib
wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dei.extendedURIBasedDispatcher=org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.IntegratorStatefulHandler
wrapper.java.additional.36 = -Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true
wrapper.java.additional.37 = -Dcarbon.components.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\wso2\\components
```

Comment: Thank you Sashika. I will try, and as soon i can i give you a feedback.

Comment: Sashika, i am really grateful with you. I was able to solve my issue. Thank you very much.